# Images not working after I save in magento

Tags: image, magento, admin

I have been using Magento for years..and I have set up over 300 products.  Today, out of nowhere I was unable to add images for my new products. I can set up everything else just fine, but when I upload a picture and save, it wont show and it appears broken.

I have cleared the cache from Magento and my browser, however the pictures are still not showing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you checked that the images are actually in the /media/catalog folder? Maybe you could try to check the permissions of that folder as well. It should be readable and executable by everyone. IMO, it's important to establish if the pictures are getting uploaded or not. If they are getting uploaded and they don't show, it sounds like a server error.

Comment: @Grampa Permissions are at 777 so I don't think that could be the issue. I contacted my host and they told me that it might be the new updated version of our PHP, which is 3.5. Could it really be a PHP issue? We're currently on Magento version 1.6.0.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I think it's PHP 5.3 that you're currently running. Still, are the pictures present in the folder on the server or not?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the .htaccess file in the media folder. After recreating it, everything was back to normal. Below is the contents of the file.

```
Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L]
</IfModule>
```